# Add and Remove Buttons JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, addition

I've tried this code that was posted but I can't get it to work the way I need. I can get it to create both fields but I can't make them look the same as the format of the first fields. How can I Add the entire section and make it look the same? and control the maximum number of activities inserted.

TIA

[This is what I'm trying to acomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arN2F.png)

```js
const addActivity = document.getElementById("add");
var i = 0;
const activityDiv = document.getElementById("Activity");

addActivity.addEventListener("click", function() {
  i++;
  const newspan = document.createElement('div');
  newspan.className = "activityGroup";
  const removeButton = document.createElement('button');
  removeButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.target.closest(".activityGroup").remove();
  });
  removeButton.className  = "delbtn";
  removeButton.innerHTML = "X";
//
  const txtfield = document.createElement('input');
  const txtarea = document.createElement('textarea');
  //
  txtfield.id = 'activity_' + i;
  txtfield.placeholder = "Activity " + i;
  newspan.appendChild(txtfield);
  //
  newspan.appendChild(txtarea);
  txtarea.id = 'activity_description_' + i;
  txtarea.placeholder = "Activity Description " + i;

  
  newspan.appendChild(removeButton);
  activityDiv.appendChild(newspan);
});
```

```css
.delbtn{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Activity">
  <div class="activityGroup">
  <input placeHolder="Type your activity" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <textarea rows="5" cols="50" placeHolder="Type your descvription"></textarea>
  <button class="delbtn">X</button>
  </div>
 <!-- Remove button -->
</div>
<button id="add">Add Activity</button>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the ([mcve]) html that’s sent to the browser, the server-side php is entirely irrelevant to the question,  and needlessly obfuscates the structure.

Comment: Just showing how I'm doing it right now

Comment: Thank you for the advice I appreciated it very much, just edited it and made it more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the problems:

> I can get it to create both fields but I can't make them look the same as the format of the first fields...

This is likely because in your original `.activityGroup` there are a number of `<br>` elements between the `<input>` and the `<textarea>` elements – incorrectly – used for spacing which you haven't inserted into the copy.

Also, two of the attributes of the original `<textarea>` (`rows="5"`, and `cols="50"`) are omitted from the one you create within the function, not to mention the line-breaks and other white-space.

This can be rectified by simply creating, and appending, those other elements:

```js
// first, some utility functions to simplify life:
const D = document,
  get = (sel, ctx = D) => ctx.querySelector(sel),
  getAll = (sel, ctx = D) => [...ctx.querySelectorAll(sel)],
  create = (tag, props) => Object.assign(D.createElement(tag), props),
  // renamed variables for consistency between JavaScript
  // and the HTML upon which it acts:
  addBtn = get("#addBtn"),
  activity = get("#activity"),
  // creating a generator function to use as a counter;
  // fundamentally this is little different from the
  // original i = 0 and then incrementing in the function
  // body, but the generator can't be affected by an
  // accidental decrement:
  iterator = function*() {
    // initial value:
    let count = 1;
    // a deliberate infinite loop, but the
    // generator function exits/pauses at
    // every yield so while this is an 'infinite
    // function' it doesn't cause any blocking:
    while (true) {
        // yields value and then increments it:
      yield count++
    }
  },
  // getting a reference to the generator function:
  counter = iterator(),
  remove = (e) => e.currentTarget.closest('div').remove();

addBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {

  // getting the current count of all elements matching
  // the selector within the document:
  const currentCount = getAll('.activityGroup').length,
            // retrieving the next value from the
        // generator function:
            i = counter.next().value;
  
  // if the currentCount is greater than 4 (again, using
  // a Yoda condition):
  if (4 < currentCount) {
    // exit the function:
    return false;
  }
  
  // creating a new <div>:
  const activityGroup = create('div', {
      // assigning the class-name of 'activityGroup':
      className: 'activityGroup'
    }),
    // creating a new <button>:
    removeButton = create('button', {
      // assigning the class-name of 'delBtn',
      className: 'delBtn',
      // and the text-content of 'X':
      textContent: 'X'
    }),
    input = create('input', {
        type: 'text',
      id: `activity_${i}`,
      placeholder: `Activity ${i}`
    }),
    textarea = create('textarea', {
        id: `activity_description_${i}`,
        placeholder: `Activity description ${i}`
    });

  // binding the remove() function as the'click' event-handler
  // on the removeButton:
  removeButton.addEventListener('click', remove);
  
  // using the HTMLElement.dataset API to set the
  // custom data-count attribute to the current
  // value of the i variable (for use in the CSS):
  activityGroup.dataset.count = i;
  // using Element.append() to append multiple elements
  // in one call:
  activityGroup.append(input, textarea, removeButton);
  activity.appendChild(activityGroup);
});
```

```css
/* caching common values (useful for theming and
   maintenance): */
:root {
  --bg-primary: hsl(0 0% 0% / 0.3);
  --columns: 2;
  --fs: 16px;
  --spacing: 0.5em;
}

/* a simple CSS reset to remove default
   margins and padding, and to have all
   elements sized in a way that includes
   their padding and border-widths in the
   assigned size: */
*,::before,::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: var(--fs);
}

#activity {
  /* using CSS Grid for layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* setting a space - held in the custom
     property - between adjacent elements: */
  gap: var(--spacing);
  /* creating a number of columns (equal to the value held
     in the --columns property) of equal width, each of one
     fraction of the remaining space) */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 1fr);
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

.activityGroup {
  /* aligning an element in the grid to the start of that
     grid (alignment is on the cross-axis of the inline-
     axis, the inline-axis being the writing direction
     of the language of the user's browser): */
  align-self: start;
  border: 0.2em solid var(--bg-primary);
  display: grid;
  gap: inherit;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

.activityGroup::before {
  background-color: var(--bg-primary);
  /* setting the content of the ::before pseudo element to the
     string of 'Activity ' concatenated with the attribute-value
     of the data-count attribute: */
  content: "Activity " attr(data-count);
  display: block;
  /* spanning all three grid-columns: */
  grid-column: span 3;
  /* applying padding to the start of the inline axis: */
  padding-inline-start: var(--spacing);
  /* moving the element outwards with negative margins,
     to place the content against the outer edges of the
     element, despite the spacing on that element: */
  margin-block-start: calc(-1 * var(--spacing));
  margin-inline: calc(-1 * var(--spacing));
}

input,
textarea {
  grid-column: span 3;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

textarea {
  min-block-size: 5em;
  resize: vertical;
}

.delBtn {
  color: red;
  grid-column: 3;
}

/* using a simple media query to modify the values of the CSS Custom
   properties as required to improve the experience on different
   devices: */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  :root {
    --columns: 1;
    --fs: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- we don't appear to be using jQuery, so I removed that <script> element -->
<!-- switching id and classes to use camelCase rather than
     having arbitrary mixed-case format; choose a style you
     prefer, but remember that consistency matters more than
     the choice you make: -->
<div id="activity">
  <div class="activityGroup">
    <input placeHolder="Type your activity" />
    <!-- removed the <br> elements, as well as the "rows" and "cols"
         attributes from the <textarea>: -->
    <textarea placeHolder="Type your description"></textarea>
    <button class="delBtn">X</button>
  </div>
  <!-- Remove button -->
</div>
<!-- changed the id from "add" to "addBtn," purely for consistency
     but, again, make your own choice on that: -->
<button id="addBtn">Add Activity</button>
```

As to your question:

> How can I [add an] entire section and...control the maximum number of activities inserted[?]

Controlling the number of total activities/sections on the page is relatively easy and simply requires you to check the number of existing sections before adding a new one:

```js
const addActivity = document.getElementById("add");
var i = 0;
const activityDiv = document.getElementById("Activity");

addActivity.addEventListener("click", function() {

  // using document.querySelectorAll() to retrieve a NodeList of all
  // elements matching the supplied CSS selector, and then retrieving
  // the length of that NodeList:
  let currentCount = document.querySelectorAll('.activityGroup').length;

  // using a "Yoda condition" to see if the currentCount is greater than
  // 4 (this approach guards against the most likely error of an assessment,
  // that of accidentally assigning a value instead of comparing); if it is:
  if (4 < currentCount) {
    // we exit the function here:
    return false;
  }

  i++;

  const newspan = document.createElement('div');
  newspan.className = "activityGroup";
  // creating a <br> element:
  const br = document.createElement('br');
  const removeButton = document.createElement('button');
  removeButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.target.closest(".activityGroup").remove();
  });
  removeButton.className = "delbtn";
  removeButton.innerHTML = "X";
  //
  const txtfield = document.createElement('input');
  const txtarea = document.createElement('textarea');
  //
  txtfield.id = 'activity_' + i;
  txtfield.placeholder = "Activity " + i;
  newspan.appendChild(txtfield);
  // appending a clone of the <br> element:
  newspan.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  // appending the <br> element:
  newspan.appendChild(br);
  //
  newspan.appendChild(txtarea);
  txtarea.id = 'activity_description_' + i;
  txtarea.placeholder = "Activity Description " + i;
  // setting the rows and cols attributes:
  txtarea.setAttribute('rows', 5);
  txtarea.setAttribute('cols', 50);
  // appending white-space (approximating what's in the HTML):
  newspan.append(document.createTextNode('\n '));

  newspan.appendChild(removeButton);
  activityDiv.appendChild(newspan);
});
```

```css
.delbtn {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Activity">
  <div class="activityGroup">
    <input placeHolder="Type your activity" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="50" placeHolder="Type your descvription"></textarea>
    <button class="delbtn">X</button>
  </div>
  <!-- Remove button -->
</div>
<button id="add">Add Activity</button>
```

Now, I'd like to improve the above functions as follows with explanatory comments in the code itself:

```js
const addActivity = document.getElementById("add");
var i = 0;
const activityDiv = document.getElementById("Activity");

addActivity.addEventListener("click", function() {

  // using document.querySelectorAll() to retrieve a NodeList of all
  // elements matching the supplied CSS selector, and then retrieving
  // the length of that NodeList:
  let currentCount = document.querySelectorAll('.activityGroup').length;

  // using a "Yoda condition" to see if the currentCount is greater than
  // 4 (this approach guards against the most likely error of an assessment,
  // that of accidentally assigning a value instead of comparing); if it is:
  if (4 < currentCount) {
    // we exit the function here:
    return false;
  }

  i++;

  const newspan = document.createElement('div');
  newspan.className = "activityGroup";
  // creating a <br> element:
  const br = document.createElement('br');
  const removeButton = document.createElement('button');
  removeButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.target.closest(".activityGroup").remove();
  });
  removeButton.className = "delbtn";
  removeButton.innerHTML = "X";
  //
  const txtfield = document.createElement('input');
  const txtarea = document.createElement('textarea');
  //
  txtfield.id = 'activity_' + i;
  txtfield.placeholder = "Activity " + i;
  newspan.appendChild(txtfield);
  // appending a clone of the <br> element:
  newspan.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  // appending the <br> element:
  newspan.appendChild(br);
  //
  newspan.appendChild(txtarea);
  txtarea.id = 'activity_description_' + i;
  txtarea.placeholder = "Activity Description " + i;
  // setting the rows and cols attributes:
  txtarea.setAttribute('rows', 5);
  txtarea.setAttribute('cols', 50);
  // appending white-space (approximating what's in the HTML):
  newspan.append(document.createTextNode('\n '));

  newspan.appendChild(removeButton);
  activityDiv.appendChild(newspan);
});
```

```css
.delbtn {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Activity">
  <div class="activityGroup">
    <input placeHolder="Type your activity" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="50" placeHolder="Type your descvription"></textarea>
    <button class="delbtn">X</button>
  </div>
  <!-- Remove button -->
</div>
<button id="add">Add Activity</button>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/j1a3mdrf/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`align-self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self).
  - [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
  - [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content).
  - [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
  - [CSS logical properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties).
  - [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
  - [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
  - [`grid-column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column).
  - [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
  - [`grid-template-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows).
  - [`inline-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inline-size).
  - [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
  - [`margin-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block).
  - [`margin-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline).
  - [`min-block-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-block-size).
  - [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).
  - [`padding-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-block).
  - [`padding-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline).
  - [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat).
  - [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var).
- JavaScript:

  - [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append).
  - [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
  - [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove).
  - [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).
  - [`Event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [Generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).
  - [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
  - [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).
  - [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).
  - [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield).

Comment: Thank you so much;
Now how can I make it 1 column?
Can I use Bootstrap?
How can add field names?

Comment: I got the name change working by adding name: `activity_${i}`, id:

Comment: I got the one-column insert changing CSS  root --columns: 1;
Thank you again very much appreciated.

Comment: I can't add the number to the first Activity = Activity 1

Comment: Thank you so much for your help is working fantastic; I'm still trying to convert the format to bootstrap 4.5 with no success if can give me a hand I really appreciated it.
This is what I have so far [Project Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/papin0/b423o5hs/329/) @david-thomas

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "If I have Activity 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and Delete 3 I want to be able to get Activities 1, 2, **4**, **5**?"

From what I've gathered, you want a button that adds and deletes activities but you only want it to work when *previous activity* isn't empty.

In the javascript, when you handle the buttons click event check *previous activity*, if it's empty, return, if it isn't empty, execute the add/delete code.

Comment: YES a button that adds and deletes activities but you only want it to work when previous activity isn't empty.